# RequireJS and JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, api, export, requirejs

I'm using a sample project from [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html#samplejquery).

Suppose I need to export some function from my module to provide some JavaScript API to the clients of my service.

But the declarations in my .js files are not visible outside RequireJS!

I add the following block to jquery-require-sample/webapp/app.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('body').alpha().beta();
   });
</script>
```

It fails: *Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'alpha'*.

Is it possible to do what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the code you provided I'm assuming you added your code after the existing script tag in app.html.  I think what you're seeing is a timing issue.  After you load the page, take a look at the `<head>` tag and you should see script tags in the following order:

1. the "require" script
2. your new script
3. alpha
4. beta

so it's running your script before the alpha and beta are run.  The reason is because require will process the first script, but not execute the "meat" of main.js until all it's dependencies are run (alpha and beta).

I hope this helps.  The following changes to your code may also illustrate what's going on.  the setTimeout gives alpha and beta a chance to load:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  setTimeout(function(){
           $(document).ready(function() {
              $('body').alpha().beta();
           });
           }, 5000);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! You're absolutely right about the cause of the problem. I find it better to trigger custom event from main.js instead of using setTimeout. But thanks, your answer was really helpful!

Comment: yeah--setTimeout usually isn't a good solution but I used it to illustrate.  glad it was helpful

Comment: Can someone explain the line $('body').alpha().beta()?
Alpha and beta seem to be separate plugins, but beta appears to be called like a member of alpha? Or is this some kind of special syntax?

Comment: @shim it has nothing to do with the actual question.  Most jQuery plugins return the jQuery object instance, to allow **method chaining**.  That's what you see here.